# Spatial Geomety SQL - two exact same queries one works the other doesn't

Tags: php, codeigniter, gis, mysql-spatial

This is bizzarre I have a database that stores polygons and a query running that checks if a point exists within any polygon and retrieves them. However when the query is created as an sql string in my php code it returns nothing however if I type in manually the query - it runs perfectly!

```
#This works
SELECT * FROM locations 
WHERE type = 'polygon' AND locationable_type = 'Notification' AND 
ST_CONTAINS(locations.geoshape, GeomFromText('Point(25.276987 55.296249)') ) ;

#This doesnt work
SELECT * FROM locations 
WHERE type = 'polygon' AND locationable_type = 'Notification' AND  
ST_CONTAINS(locations.geoshape, GeomFromText('Point(‎25.276987 55.296249)') );
```

Heres how the sql i actually being generated:

public function get_by_coords($latitude, $longitude){

```
// this grabs all the notifications
$sql = sprintf("SELECT * FROM locations WHERE type = 'polygon' AND locationable_type = 'Notification' 
        AND ST_CONTAINS(locations.geoshape, GeomFromText('point(%s, %s)') )", ($latitude), ($longitude));
```

Where `$latitude, $longitude` are actually passed as strings from a GET variable. I tried to typecast but the result was:

```
$latitude = "25.276987";
(float)$latitude; // equals zero
```

Whats going on here? I'm using Codeigniter here.

UPDATE

I just did a var_dump and found something weird. If I var_dump the created SQL query it shows there are 6 more characters than if I var_dump the query directly typed in a string ie:

```
string(166) "SELECT * FROM locations  WHERE type = 'polygon' AND locationable_type = 'Notification' AND  ST_CONTAINS(locations.geoshape, Point('‎25.27116987','‎55.292216249'))"
string(160) "SELECT * FROM locations  WHERE type = 'polygon' AND locationable_type = 'Notification' AND  ST_CONTAINS(locations.geoshape, Point('25.27116987','55.292216249'))"
```

The first string is generated while the second was as is - its shows there are 6 extra characters in the first string - I have a weird feeling those are causing issues.. how do I go further here...

Comment: Try printing the query with the parameters and then fire it on it server..check if it is working then or not..as  U told u tried manually and it worked.

Comment: Also in the second query which u have posted contains the coordinates separated with comma which is not present in ur first query.

Comment: DId that infact just changed the comma to exactly what was outputted out. No change - the first query gives me a result the other one gives nothing. Its as though the coordinates are totally ignored.

Comment: Have u tried printing the query and the parameters ? and then run the outputted query in your mysql server.

Comment: The above query which doesnt run was outputted using an echo statement - the one that does is typed in :(

Comment: I think I made a breakthrough - please check the question

Comment: If it is just adding extra spaces and if only that is the issue then add a trim function and check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey guys sorry for the late response. I managed to find out what the issue was. I did a simple strlen on the sql generated vs the sql manually typed in and found a discrepency in the length. There were some kind of hidden characters - so did a simple remove non printable characters and it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I remember in php functions we'll still need the dollar sign in front of the arguments.

as you do  `....($latitude), ($longitude));` within the function

thus your function arguments should be

```
public function get_by_coords($latitude,$longitude){

$sql = sprintf("SELECT * FROM locations WHERE type = 'polygon' AND locationable_type = 'Notification' 
        AND ST_CONTAINS(locations.geoshape, GeomFromText('point(%s, %s)') )", ($latitude), ($longitude));
}
```

Comment: There isn't comma `,` in the `point(...)` that separates *latitute* & *longitude*, but you put it on.  Moreover are these *locations.geoshape* & *GeomFromText* actually variables or function coming from outside the function? It's either a scope issue or *'point(%s, %s)')* is intepreted as plain string like *'point(25.276987 55.296249)')*.

Comment: I think I made some progress - can you check the question